# How to convert strings/text to EBCDIC in JS?

Tags: javascript, ascii, ebcdic

I am in the process of writing a website that accepts user input of at least 256 characters/strings (code checks for that requirement), prompts(also checks) the user's choice of conversion (user selects either ASCII or EBCDIC), and outputs the converted text string onto the page (in ASCII or EBCDIC based on user's preference). The code is capable of printing out the user input (checking for minimum input of 256 characters and making sure the user selects a radio button before pressing the Run! button). The code below has the following with comments explaining the functions:

encoding.js:

```
function myFunction() {

    //Get both elements
    const ascii = document.getElementById('ascii')
    const ebcdic = document.getElementById('ebcdic')

    let str = document.getElementById("text_id");
    let a = "ASCII Code is == >  ";

    // Below checks to see if the user selects writed more than 255 chars
    if (str.value.length < 256) {
        console.log("null");
        return null;
        // prints and returns null if the user entered a string less than 256 characters
    }

    // Below checks to see if the user selects a radio button
    let radio_selected = false;
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function (radio) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            radio_selected = true;
        }
    })
    if (!radio_selected) {
        console.log("The radio has not been checked, please select a button");
        return;
    }
    
    //If one of the elements is checked it triggers a condition, if the other is cheked it triggers the other condition
    if (ascii.checked) {
        for (let i = 0; i < str.value.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + str.value.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    }
    else if (ebcdic.checked) {
        for (let i = 0; i < str.value.length; i++) { //loop to check all values entered
        //Code to convert text to EBCDIC, need help with this
        }
    }
}
```

1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Converter for ASCII or EBCDIC</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="encoding.js" defer></script>
   </head>

   <body style="text-align:center;">
    <label for="text">Enter a text that is at least 256 characters long</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text_id" name="text" minlength="256">

    <p>Select the following:</p>
    <div>
        <input id="ascii" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ascii">
        <label for="ascii">ASCII</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="ebcdic" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ebcdic">
        <label for="ebcdic">EBCDIC</label>
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">"Run!"</button>
    <label for="button">"Run!"</label>
    <p id="demo" style="color:red;">
   </body>
</html>
```

I have been browsing this site for any sign of text/string (not single characters) conversion to EBCDIC. So far, I've only seen EBCDIC to ASCII, the reverse, and individual character conversions but no sign of string/text to EBCDIC conversions.

Comment: EBCDIC? Is this program for time travelers from the 60's?

Comment: What's the problem? If you know how to convert individual characters to EBCDIC, just loop over the characters in the string.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? *charCodeAt()* returns a 1-to 3 digit number representing the encoding value for the character. Concatenating all those 1-to-3 digit numbers simply results in a long string of digits where the boundaries of the individual characters disappear. I'd rather display the hexadecimal representation of the values.

Comment: You should clear the content of element *demo*. As it stands, new data is just appended to the previous result whenever the *Run* button is pressed.

Comment: JS doesn't seem to offer an *iconv()* functions as other languages do. *iconv()* is used to translate string data fome one code page to another one. Lack of this function, you need implement this yourself for the code pages of your choice (*note* that there isn't simply *EBCDIC*; you need to decide which *EBCDIC code page* or *code pages* you want to support.

Comment: @Barmar: EBCDIC is well alive today. IBM Z mainframe systems and IBM AS/400 midrange systems (usually) encode character data in any one of the EBCDIC code pages.

Comment: What I'm wanting the program to do is to convert the user's entered text into hexadecimal EBCDIC.

Comment: This is the code table I'm looking at: http://ascii-table.com/ebcdic-table.php

Comment: @sierra117 Use that to create an array that contains the mapping from ASCII codes to the corresponding EBCDIC codes. Then loop over the indexes in the input string, call `charCodeAt(i)` to get its ASCII code, and find the translation in the array.

Comment: @sierra117: The table at the link doesn't say which code pages these are. Be ware that many characters are missing, e.g. all the accented characters. The user may well be able to type them, but the code would not be able translate. So, prepare for the case and act appropriately.

Comment: This one does help but I see what you mean, especially with accented characters. Assuming the user does not user accent characters, this should work with loop.

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc311/clin-cmsc311/Lectures/lecture6/ebcdic.html

Comment: Not sure why you think that table helps more than the other one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no javascript programmer, so I cannot help with the code, but I'll try to outline the steps you need to be able to write the code for the ASCII to EBCDIC conversion.

- You need to build a 256 element translation table.
- The index into the table is the value you get by calling charCodeAt() for each single character of the input field.
- The element value at that index is the EBCDIC value for the corresponding ASCII character. As an example, let's take character "A". This has the ASCII value 65 (decimal), and the EBCDIC value 193 (decimal). So the entry at index 65 holds the value 193.
- Use some special some value, e.g. 991, if the ASCII character does not have a representation in the EBCDIC table.
- Do this for every (printable) ASCII character.
- Once all the entries for (printable) ASCII characters have been filled, you need to fill the remaining entries. Again use some value, e.g. 992.
- The loop uses the charCodeAt() value for each input character to index into the table. The value found is then either the value for the character in EBCDIC, or the indication for a non-translatable character (991), or for a non-printable character (992).

Hope this helps you to start with coding.